# Automatically resize elements when changing orientation in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app layout doesn't have any issues when in portrait mode, but when I change the orientation to landscape, there are some issues:

1. The app bar, which is minimized by default, is larger in landscape mode and overlaps the first button and the browser window
2. The URL text box and the Go button disappear when in landscape orientation.

   ```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Button x:Name="ButtonOne" Content="ButtonOne" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButtonOne_Click" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <Button x:Name="ButtonTwo" Content="ButtonTwo" Click="ButtonTwo_Click" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="1"/>
   </Grid>

   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
       <TextBox x:Name="URL" Margin="0,545,69,-41" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="http://www.xbox.com" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75"/>
       <Button x:Name="Go" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,545,0,-41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Go_Click" Height="75"/>
       <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MiniBrowser" Margin="10,-25,10,79"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

   ```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
   <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized">
       <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
           <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="Item1_Click" Text="Item 1"/>
       </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
   </shell:ApplicationBar>
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
   ```

So what I would like to have is:

1. An app bar that doesn't overlap with the page content
2. If possible, I would like to hide the URL bar and the Go button when in landscape mode, and have the browser windows fill all available space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlap probably occurs because you try to position the controls hard coded by setting the margins. You better put your controls in a grid like this and remove `Mode=Minimized` from the application bar:

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" >
      <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem  Text="Item 1"/>
      </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <phone:WebBrowser Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="MiniBrowser"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="URL" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="http://www.xbox.com" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Go" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Go_Click" Height="75"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hiding the textbox and the button can be done in the `OrientationChanged` event of the page:

```
private void MainPage_OnOrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{

    // Switch the visibility of the controls based on an orientation change.
    if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
    {
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
        URL.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Go.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    // If not in portrait, hide controls.
    else
    {
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
        URL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        Go.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

In order for this eventhandler to work you need to add `OrientationChanged="MainPage_OnOrientationChanged"` to your MainPage.xaml (as an attribute of the `phone:PhoneApplicationPage` element.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the XAML code doesn't make the layout appear correctly (among other things, the browser window just occupies half of the screen). In the C# code, is there perhaps something that is missing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from development tools. I'll look in to it tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much, the URL bar is correctly hidden now! However, some overlapping still occurs (I have uploaded a screenshot). Is this normal? (upvote for now :) )

Comment: Unfortunately a `Minimized` `ApplicationBar` is not supported in landscape mode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.mode(v=vs.105).aspx). One way to work around that is to set the mode in the OnOrientationChanged handler. Have a look at the updated code.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! So you have to specifically set the application bar mode to default in the code, I thought that not setting it was the same...